Samsung Android USB Devices not Recognized by Win10 Vbox Guest
I'm doing tests to see if I can switch from Win to Ubuntu as my host OS. There are a handful of Win APPs I rely on heavily that are not available for LINUX. Guidance from the OEMs providing those APPs (Adobe, Logitech, Pentair, Garmin, Sigma, Samsung among them) is to run the APPs within a Win VM. And that works well for all the APPs except the Samsung SmartSwitch backup/restore APP. The Win10 VM doesn't recognize the Android USB devices when connected. It recognizes that a USB device has been attached, and puts up a notification that the device is being installed. Installation appears to never complete because the device is never visible from Explorer. So of course the SmartSwitch APP never finds the device.
The LINUX host recognizes the Android device, and I can browse its contents through the LINUX Files APP. But it looks like identifying meta data isn't getting through to the VM guest. There are APPs besides the Samsung APP (e.g. Logitech MyHarmony, Garmin Express) which have no trouble reading and writing USB devices from those vendors when attached to the VM guest.
Is there a known fix for this? Perhaps I'm missing a driver?
Software config:
Uname -a = 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu
VirtualBox, Guest Additions and Extension Pack = 7.0.16_Ubuntur162802
Samsung Windows USB Driver for Mobile Phones = 1.7.610
Samsung Smart Switch Win APP = 4.3.24062_1
64 bit Windows 10.0.19045
